# Is the following true: an infinite set is countable iff every element has a finite representation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think this works for the following: real numbers: uncountable and infinitely long elements, integers: countable and elements of finite length.

Comment: What is a representation of an element in a set?

Comment: And whatever it means, why couldn't we just take a countably infinite subset of numbers without a finite representation?

Comment: @pjs36 Heh, good point.

Comment: @pjs36 I think you raise the point that the condition "has a finite representation" is not well defined here.  I mean you could take a set of transcendental real numbers and give them short names, like $\pi$.  So to make the condition well defined I think you reduce the statement to a tautology.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yeah, I assume that "finite representation" is going to be a sticking point here, it's probably going to be hard to define (unless it just means irrational). So, rather than deal with *that* aspect, it just seems prudent to mention that you can have countable subsets of uncountably infinite sets, so no "iff."

Comment: Of course you need to give a definition of "has a finite representation". There are various ways you could do that; for some of them it is clear that there are only countably many finite representations, so in that case it will be true that if every element of $S$ has a finite representation then $S$ is countable. _But_ the converse is going to be false, unless you have a wacky notion of "finite representation" such that _every_ real has a finite representation: If $x$ is a real with no finite representation then $\{x\}$ is a countable set where not every element has a finite representation.

Comment: Oh - you asked about _infinite_ sets. Converse is still false, unless "has a finite representation" is true of all but finitely many reals...

Comment: But irrational numbers that are algebraic always have finite representation because they can be represented as the roots of specific monic polynomials with rational coefficients.  And you can always represent polynomials with rational coefficients in a finite way.

Comment: I don't know enough vocab to make good definition, but I would call a representation of a number as a sequence of nice operations on nice numbers... Like 3 + 6/7 + 7^2 + sqrt(2) + pi. Nice meaning: from a countable subset of all functions/numbers

Answer (score 0):

To avoid discussions about our background theory, let's say that we work in $\operatorname{ZFC}$.

---

First let me say that the answer to your question - as stated - is no, because for any set $x$ the set $\{x\}$ is certainly at most countable (if you want to talk about infinite sets only - consider $\{x\} \cup \mathbb N_0 = \{x,0,1,2, \ldots \}$). If $x$ **doesn't have a finite representation** (I will talk about the meaning of this later), this demonstrates that the answer to your question is "no".

However, you might be interested in the following: I think it is reasonable to say that a set $x$ has a *finite representation* if and only if it has only finitely many elements and each of these elements has only finitely many elements and each of these also has only finitely many elements... I.e. $x$ has a *finite representation* if and only if *$x$ is [hereditarily finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set)*. Let $V_\omega$ be the set of all heriditarily finite sets. Then there is a 'natural' bijection (due to Ackermann) $A \colon \mathbb N_0 \to V_\omega$ which is recursivley defined by $A(0) = \emptyset$ and $A(2^{x_1} + 2^{x_2} + \ldots, 2^{x_k}) = \{A(x_1), \ldots, A(x_k)\}$, where $x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_k$ are natural numbers.

Therefore any set $X$ that only contains hereditarily finite sets is countable (as $X \subseteq V_\omega$ and the latter is countable). As one may construct $\mathbb N_0, \mathbb Z$ and in fact any countable group / order / language / automata / ... as a subset of $V_\omega$, while no uncountable structure can consist of only hereditarily finite sets, this may be regarded as an answer to a refined version of your question.